# Fixed points of polynomial ring homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, fixed-point-theorems, symmetric-polynomials, invariant-theory

> $S=\mathbb R[x+y+z, xy+yz+zx, xyz]$ is the ring of the symmetric polynomials in $\mathbb R[x,y,z]$. Let $\psi\colon S \to R[x,y,z]$ be a *ring homomorphism* such that
>   \begin{align}
> x &\mapsto -x,\\
> y &\mapsto z-x, \\
> z &\mapsto y-x.
> \end{align}
>   I'd like to know how to find the fixed points of $\psi$, that is the polynomials $p$ such $\psi(p)=p$, or equivalently such that $p(x,y,z)=p(-x,z-x,y-x)$ (apart from the constant polynomials).

We have 
\begin{align}
a = x+y+z &\mapsto -3x+y+z = A\\
b= xy+yz+zx &\mapsto 3  x^2 - 2 xy - 2xz + y z = B\\
c= xyz &\mapsto -x^3 + x^2 y + x^2 z - x y z = C .
\end{align}

So far I've found that $C= - c + x^2 (A-2x)$ and $B+Ax= - b + 2 yz$, but I cannot easily get rid of those $x,y,z$, and actually I'm just blindly trying to find some relations and hopefully some fixed points. Even if I found any of those polynomials, I still wouldn't know if there aren't others... Any help to untangle this mess would be very appreciated, as well as some reference on the topic of invariant polynomials :)

Comment: why are you talking about $S$ at all ?

Comment: @mercio, because this is just part of the problem, which is to find the invariant polynomials under a group of linear maps. I did find that these polynomials must be symmetric and invariant under $\psi$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find polynomials that are invariant by both $\psi$, and the natural action of $S_3$ on $\Bbb R[x,y,z]$, so it's natural to look at the subgroup $G$ of $Aut(\Bbb R[x,y,z])$ generated by $\psi$ and $S_3$.

It turns out that $G$ is isomorphic to $S_4$.

Since our copy of $S_3$ in $G$ looks just like a copy of $S_3$ in $S_4$ (a normalizer of an element in the set on which $S_4$ acts), $G$ is the group of permutations of $G/S_3$. A natural polynomial invariant by $S_3$ is $T = x+y+z$, its other images by $G$ are then $X = -3x+y+z, Y = x-3y+z$, and $Z = x+y-3z$.

Now then it is easy to check that $G$ is the group of permutations of $\{X;Y;Z;T\}$, because the action of $S_3$ on $x,y,z$ is translated into the same action on $X,Y,Z$ ; and $\psi(X,Y,Z,T) = (T,Z,Y,X)$

Now let $X,Y,Z,T$ be indeterminates and let $\phi : \Bbb R[X,Y,Z,T] \to \Bbb R[x,y,z]$ be defined by $\phi(X) = -3x+y+z$ etc. $G$ acts on both rings and its action is compatible with $\phi$ ($\phi$ is a map of $G$-modules).

$\phi$ has a right-inverse $\sigma :\Bbb R[x,y,z] \to \Bbb R[X,Y,Z,T]$ defined for example by $\sigma(x) = (T-X)/4$ etc, which shows that $\phi$ is surjective.
In fact one can show that $\sigma$ is also a map of $G$-modules (this is pretty clear for the $S_3$ part of $G$ so you only need to check that $\psi$ commutes with $\sigma$)

This shows that $\Bbb R[X,Y,Z,T]$ is the direct sum of $\ker \phi$ and $\sigma(\Bbb R[x,y,z])$ (as $G$-modules), and that all the invariants in $\Bbb R[x,y,z]$ come from invariants in $\Bbb R[X,Y,Z,T]$.

But it is well-known that $\Bbb R[X,Y,Z,T]^G = \Bbb R[E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4]$ where the $E_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in $X,Y,Z,T$.

$\phi(E_1) = 0$, (in fact $\ker \phi = (E_1)$) ;  but you get
$\phi(E_2) = -6(x^2+y^2+z^2)+4(xy+yz+zx)$
$\phi(E_3) = -8(x^3+y^3+z^3)+8(x^2y+x^2z+xy^2+xz^2+y^2z+yz^2)-16xyz$
$\phi(E_4) = -3(x^4+y^4+z^4)+4(x^3y+x^3z+xy^3+xz^3+y^3z+yz^3) +14(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2) -20xyz(x+y+z)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems that I lack much of the knowledge needed to understand it, though. I'll have to spend some time on it. By the way, do you know any reference for studying this topic of invariant polynomials?

Comment: i think the basics should be covered in computational algebraic geometry courses