# Reference request: invariant theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources, invariant-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
$Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $A$ a finite subgroup of $\GL_n\mathbb K$. For each $M \in \GL_n\mathbb K$, let's define a ring endomorphism $\psi_M \in \End \mathbb K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto M \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n 
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation}

$f \in \mathbb K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is called *invariant* under $A$ if $\psi_M(f) = f$, for all $M \in A$. The problem is to find the ring of the invariants. For example, for $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$, $n=2$ and $A =\langle -I_2\rangle$, the ring of the invariants is $\mathbb R[x^2,y^2,xy]$. A more complex example can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852286/fixed-points-of-polynomial-ring-homomorphism). We can do the same with rational functions instead of polynomials, can't we? I'm not sure the term *invariant theory* is the correct one, though.

Are there any books or lecture notes about this topic?

Comment: I have no idea about litterature for invariant theory for rationnal functions. For invariants of finite groups there are lot of reference : a PDF by Procesi and Kraft : http://jones.math.unibas.ch/~kraft/docs/primernew.pdf or this article by Stanley : http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/38.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You are living in the era of internet and google. Existence question can be easily settled. For finite group invariants and algorithmic oriented treatment see the book by B. Sturmfels or the one by H. Derksen & G. Kemper.

For invariants of linear algebraic groups see the books by 
Dolgachev, or the one by Procesi. There is one by Mumford Geometric Invariant Theory which revived the subject in 1960s. And the  one by Dieudonne & Carrel gives historical account.